# Spring appears to ignore required=false request parameters

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Any help please as this all looks fine to me. I have a `@RestController` that I want to have a method that has optional `ZonedDateTime` request parameters that indicate the start/end of a date range for a query,

```
@GetMapping("/api/v1/user/{userID}/resource/{resourceID}/data")
public ResponseEntity<String> getResourceData(
        @PathVariable String userID,
        @PathVariable String resourceID,
        @RequestParam(name = "start", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)  ZonedDateTime start,
        @RequestParam(name = "end", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)  ZonedDateTime end
)
```

the path variables work fine but when I try and hit the end point with valid dates they just seem to get ignored, e.g.

```
curl  http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user/a/resource/a/data?start=2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z&end=2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must remember to use quotes to wrap URL in curl command and correctly match expected date format(s) for ISO 8601